# Sublime Text 2 won't open after install

Tags: text-editor, sublime-text

I just installed Sublime Text 2 using this [guide](http://tutology.net/category/editors/sublime-text-editor-linux)
modified for Xubuntu 12.04.
After following the instructions, logging out and back in, Sublime was in my application list but it won't open. 
When I try to open it from the terminal I get this message:

```
 /opt/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text: 1: /opt/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text: Syntax error:   word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I've double checked the two files I created `/usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop` and `/usr/bin/sublime` and they are both correct. I'm not sure what to try next.

Note: I am a complete and utter novice and followed the instructions blindly so bear with me.

Comment: It might be because you're trying to run the 64 bit version on 32 bit machine. Post the output of `uname -a`.